# What's the difference between drive up to and drive to/go up to and go to?

Tags: difference

What does up imply here?

- A jeep drove up to the stone marker and stopped. (from a novel)
- A jeep drove to the stone marker and stopped. (a made up example)
- A guy came up to a girl and grabbed her by her waist. (a made up example)
- A guy came to a girl and grabbed her by her waist. (a made up example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differences are in tone and would depend on context.

"Drove (came) up to"  suggests a deliberate, intended action with a particular goal. Just "Drove (came) to" is less forceful.

In the first pair of sentences the first suggests that the plot of the novel might depend on something about the stone marker, while the second could be specifying where the driver of the jeep was planning to meet someone.

In the second pair of sentences the "grabbed her by her waist" is so strong that the second version would be surprisingly weak prose.